# pdo_mysql extension is not installed error on xampp server

Tags: mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

I'm facing this extension error on local machine. I also checked pdo_mysql extension install on my server. It show enable status during execute command, 
which is:

> php -i | grep PDO

It shows `PDO support => enabled`.

But execute some indexing command it seems error.
I'm using php 5.6.20 and MySQL v5.6+

[image]

Comment: In ubuntu, it is good if you use LAMP server.